# Rails is not routing to my webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have been setting up a demo page to test stuff out but on my app I set up, my routes aren't being set up for some reason. This is my routing file: http://electrithm.net/routes.rb

Answer (score 2):

Trying specifying your route like:

```
get 'hw/hworld', to: 'hw/hworld'
```

And then implement your controller+action:

```
class HwController < ApplicationController
  def hworld

    render # should render app/views/hw/hworld.html.erb
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing some unconventional things, like having a non-plural object, and Rails is all about "convention over configuration" but your example will still work.

Assuming you are trying to go to `http://yourwebsite/hw/hworld` then your route should be:

```
get "hw/hworld" => "hw#hworld"
```

In the above example you are saying, "when someone goes to the path `/hw/hworld` on my website send the request to the hw controller, HwController, and the hworld action, or method, in that controller."

Your controller file should be `app/controllers/hw_controller.rb` and should read:

```
class HwController < ApplicationController
  def hworld
    render
  end
end
```

And you should have a view file in `app/views/hw/hworld.html.erb`. Mine simply says:

```
This is the HWorld page
```

Now when I run `rails s` and go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/hw/hworld` I get:

```
This is the HWorld page
```

As is expected.

You can see the full source code here:  https://github.com/mikbe/hworld

Make sure you check out the Rails routing guide as well:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

In addition there's an excellent Rails tutorial that will take you step-by-step through building a Rails website here (you can read it for free online):
https://www.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please accept my apology telling that, but please consider to follow for at least official Rails Guides... It will be tough I'n sure, however your understanding will be improved dramatically. In `routes.rb` you provided there is a error:

```
get 'hw/hworld', action: 'hw/hworld.html.erb'
```

You are trying to map route directly to view. I can guess you didn't realize or understand MVC conception. That why I suggest to learn. Good luck!